# what is the difference between bench and data access framework in spring?

Tags: java, spring

what is the difference between batch and data access framework in spring? Please anyone provide the practical specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as for the IT words :

- Batch : Batch processing is execution of a series of programs ("jobs") on a computer without manual intervention. ([Batch processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing))
- Data access framework : the framework to access the data from repositories (databases, etc ...).

These are 2 different concepts.